# No installed app with label 'flatpages' Django

Tags: django, django-flatpages

I am having a strange problem with flatpages 
1 - My project was using django 1.3. In that, we copied django flatpages content and modified it for our needs.
2 - But now when we upgraded to django 1.7. In admin, console I am getting no installed app with label 'flatpages'

inside flatpages/**init**.py

```
   default_app_config = 'path.to.FlatPageConfig'
```

settings.py has in INSTALLED_APPS

```
   'path.to.FlatPageConfig' #custom flatpage implementation
```

and as per django 1.7 I have created a AppConfig for that

```
class FlatPageConfig(AppConfig):
   name = 'flatpages' # name of custom flatpage implementation
   label = 'myFlatpages'
   verbose_name = 'My FlatPages'
```

Comment: It might be a typo, but `init.py` should be `__init__.py`

Comment: it is __init__.py and no typo

Comment: Timmy is right, the `init.py` should be `__init__.py`

Comment: It is __init__.py  somehow stackoverflow didn't print it like that.